# Cannot create multidimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array of workers named `$workers` and there jobs named `$jobs`. Lets, each day they can do `$jobs_for_each` nos. of job. Now I need to create an array for there daily jobs. Here is my code:

```
$all_workers=array("worker1","worker2","worker3","worker4", ... ... );
$all_jobs=array("j1","j2","j3", .... .... );
$jobs_for_each=7;
$k=0;
$day=0;
for ($n=0; $n < 3; $n++) 
{ 
   for ($j=0; $j < count($all_workers) ; $j++) 
   {
      for ($i=0; $i < $jobs_for_each; $i++) 
      {
         $job_arr[$day][trim($all_workers[$j])][]=trim($all_jobs[($k*$jobs_for_each)+$i]);
         $distributed_arr[]=trim($all_jobs[($k*$jobs_for_each)+$i]);
      }
      $k++; 
   }
   $remaining=array_diff ( $all_jobs , $distributed_arr );
   unset($all_jobs);
   $all_jobs = $remaining;
   if (empty($all_jobs))
   {
      $n=5;
   }
   else
   {
      $n=0;
      array_values($all_jobs);
   }
   $k=0;
   $day++;
}
```

This code is not working. I need `$job_arr` in formate of `$job_arr[day][worker]=array(jobs);`

If my worker is `4` and jobs is `100` jobs fir each per day is `7`
then it shoult take 4 days and some worker should not get job at last day;

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't initialising `$job_arr`as an array, or any of it's elements as arrays either, before trying to set them.

Comment: `$job_arr` shoud automeicaly initialise.

Comment: @Matt-SL you do not have to initialize variables in php.

Comment: You have to define $job_arr[$day] , enable notice : Notice: Undefined offset: 3

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I wasn't aware that applied to arrays or multidimensional arrays! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Poignant I have not given full array here, i have used "... ...." so it is undefined

Comment: Why my question is getting down vote? can anybody explain

Comment: Check my answer, i have edited to make an equal repartition when $job_left <= $jobs_for_each*$count_workers

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant yes i have seen that. thanks for your nice answer. But what is the problem with my question according to guidline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make some change in second part and add isset :

```
    <?php
    $all_workers=array("worker1","worker2","worker3","worker4");
    $count_workers = count($all_workers);
    $all_jobs=array("j1","j2","j3","j4","j5","j6","j7","j8","j9","j10");
    $jobs_for_each=2;
    $k=0;
    $day=0;
    for ($n=0; $n < 3; $n++) 
    { 
        for ($j=0; $j < $count_workers ; $j++) 
        {
              for ($i=0; $i < $jobs_for_each; $i++) 
              {
                if(!isset($job_arr[$day])){
                    $job_arr[$day]=array();
                }

                 $job_left = count($all_jobs);
                  if( $job_left <= $jobs_for_each*$count_workers){
                      $jobs_for_each = ceil($job_left / $count_workers);
                  }
                 if(!isset($all_jobs[($k*$jobs_for_each)+$i])){
                    echo 'no more job<br />';break(3);
                 }else{
                     $job_arr[$day][trim($all_workers[$j])][]=trim($all_jobs[($k*$jobs_for_each)+$i]);
                     $distributed_arr[]=trim($all_jobs[($k*$jobs_for_each)+$i]);
                 }
              }
              $k++; 
        }


        $remaining=array_diff ( $all_jobs , $distributed_arr );
        if (empty($remaining))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $all_jobs = array_values($remaining);
        }
        $k=0;
        $day++;
    }
    ?>
```

Will ouput :

```
no more job
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'worker1' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'j1' (length=2)
          1 => string 'j2' (length=2)
      'worker2' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'j3' (length=2)
          1 => string 'j4' (length=2)
      'worker3' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'j5' (length=2)
          1 => string 'j6' (length=2)
      'worker4' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'j7' (length=2)
          1 => string 'j8' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'worker1' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'j9' (length=2)
          1 => string 'j10' (length=3)
```